# Log function for debug console is not working on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, debugging

`log()` function from `'dart:developer'` is not working. Nothing is being printed on debug console. Currently I'm using the logger package for debugging console, but it seems to truncate long log messages, similar to the `print()` function. As a result, I'm unable to see the complete output during debugging.

I also explored using `debugPrint()`, but it's not ideal as it requires additional effort to locate and read the printed logs, making debugging more cumbersome.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with the logger package or found a better alternative for debugging console printing in Flutter? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use Android Studio? It is common issue on VS code to cut your long console logs